# Error while migrating from EC2 to Google Cloud Compute: "The referenced network resource cannot be found."

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to migrate my Ubuntu 14.04.3 AWS EC2 instance to Google Cloud Compute.

I followed all the instructions given by Google at this page: [Import an Amazon Machine Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#import_an_ami_image), and once I had the image showing up in my Google Cloud Compute dashboard, I tried launching an instance from it.

The following error showed up:
[image: Google Cloud compute instances list]

I tried looking into this instance through gcloud sdk, by running `gcloud compute instances list` but it showed that I do not have any instance running.

While creating the instance in the Google Cloud interface, I tried changing some settings.  I tried both the possibilities for `Allow HTTP Traffic` and `Allow HTTPS traffic`. Also, I tried going into the tabs just below that, and tweaking the 'Networking' tab. Here is what the wizard looked like before I clicked on the 'Networking' tab:

[image: 'Create' button enabled before clicking on 'Networking' tab]

Surprisingly, as soon as I clicked on the 'networking' tab, the 'Create' button below got disabled. I had no way to bring it back - I tried clicking on the 'Network' drop down in the 'Networking' tab, but it was empty! Chose various options for 'External IP' field, the 'Create' button was still disabled.

[image]

I've been really racking my brains on what's going wrong, and so far I haven't been able to make any sense of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to create a new network? A network should exist in order to create an instance. From your cloud console, navigate to networking > Networks > create network. Once done, navigate to Compute engine and try to create the instance using the AWS image created.

Comment: @George Please post your comment as an answer so that others can give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnsonCharles done and thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to create a new network? A network should exist in order to create an instance. From your cloud console, navigate to networking > Networks > create network. Once done, navigate to Compute engine and try to create the instance using the AWS image created.